# magento if on category page

Tags: category, javascript

I'm trying to display javascript code if a user is on category page, however my code is displaying on all the pages including product page.

```
<?php
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

if ($_category->getId()) {
      echo '<script>
jQuery(function($){
var url = window.location.href; 
window.location.href = url+"#dir=desc&order=bestsellers";
});
</script>';
}
  else {

      echo '';
  }


?>
```

Comment: your code is working fine. what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Yeah, my code is working fine on category but I don't want it to work on other pages such as  product pages, cms, etc. So only category page.

Answer (score 1):

create a new js file with your js code in it and add it into your js in the skin in your theme.

and in your local.xml file add the following code

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/yourjs.js</name</action>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if you're on a category page, use:

```
$frontEnd = Mage::app()->getFrontController();

if ($frontEnd->getRequest()->getRouteName() === 'catalog' && $frontEnd->getAction()->getFullActionName() === 'catalog_category_view') {
```

Comment: I tried.. It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code :

```
    <?php
    $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
     $currentAction = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); 
    if ($currentAction == 'category') {
      echo '<script>
    jQuery(function($){
     var url = window.location.href; 
    window.location.href = url+"#dir=desc&order=bestsellers";
    });
    </script>';
    }
      else {

          echo '';
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: There was a minor issue in my code i have fixed it.Please try and let me know if its work for you.

Comment: its not working..

Comment: Have you tried my updated code ?

Comment: Yes Arunendra, your code is giving error Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Comment: Remove  $_category->getId()  from if condition see updated answer

Comment: Well your given code is working but code is working on all pages and not just category page

Comment: Have you cleared cache i have checked this code on my site and it's working only on category page

Comment: Not working even after clearing cache..